# Passing props from Container with fetch to one element via Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a bit hypotetical situation as i do not have live example. My question is:

I have some random data:

- id
- name
- description
- link
- photo
- github
- short description

I have a Projects.js component where I am fetching data

```
 render() {
    const { projects } = this.state;
    return (
          <div className='Projects__Content'>
            {projects .map(project => {
              return (
                <div key={project.id} className='Projects__Project'>
                  <h3>{project.name}</h3>
                   <p>{projects.shortDescription}</p>
                   <Link to=`/project/${project.id}`/>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
    );
  }
```

So here in my Projects.js I am rendering all projects that I have in my data, but only I am using some information. From my rendered projects with React Router Link, I want to go to specific project using ID. For that part I have another component Project.js.

Now in Project.js I want to use all data that I fetched in Projects.js, but part is that I am not getting right. Can I pass a props all my fetched data? During my search I found that I should not pass props with Link.
So can I do this like this:

```
 render() {
    const { projects } = this.state;
    return (
          <div className='Projects__Content'>
            {projects .map(project => {
              return (
                <div key={project.id} className='Projects__Project'>
                  <h3>{project.name}</h3>
                   <p>{projects.shortDescription}</p>
                   <Link to=`/project/${project.id}`/>

                </div>
              );
            })}
          <Project dataProps={...projects} />
          </div>
    );
  }
```

But this will render my one project from Project.js, so this is not what I want.
How about this:

```
 render() {
    const { projects } = this.state;
    return (
          <div className='Projects__Content'>
            {projects .map(project => {
              return (
                <div key={project.id} className='Projects__Project'>
                  <h3>{project.name}</h3>
                   <p>{projects.shortDescription}</p>
                   <Link to=`/project/${project.id}` propsData={...projects}/>

                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
    );
  }
```

Or maybe I should use another fetch in Project.js
With redux I can use one reducer to do that, but how this should be handled with React only?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `Project` component which will be used to show the Project details.

The part that is troubling you is that you should have some kind of routing to know which Project to show and you already have link defined, so just add a project route at `/project/:projectId`.

There are 3 ways that you can share your projects array with project:

1. Just pass the whole object along you already have in projects component down to project component
2. Use Redux of some state management to store it globally
3. Fetch project individually inside project component by project id

Comment: okay. so all my thoughs were on point. But what is the best way to do such thing?

Comment: It all depends on your project architecture(and on bunch other things). For beginner I would recommend implementing the 3rd option, this will be the fastest to implement.